Querying azure synape serverless through SQL server management studio getting ERROR
Querying azure synape serverless through SQL server management studio getting below ERROR.
Content of directory on path 'Tables/Finance/AccountsReceivable/Transaction/CustTrans/*.csv' cannot be listed.
Appreciated your support..
expected to resolve the issue.
